# How simulate a key event with GDK?

Tags: c, gdk

I need for an application to generate a key event in order to emulate a keyboard.

Comment: Please explain your question properly. provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you can use e.g. [`gdk_display_put_event()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkDisplay.html#gdk-display-put-event), but your question is not very clear.

Do you expect other applications than your own to see the emulated keyboard events? Not sure GDK can do that.